# How to upload custom artifact after it was build using a windows bat command?

Tags: installation, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a windows batch file to create me a file myUser.aaa.

And I call this bat file using exec-maven-plugin

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>scripts/MyBat.bat</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

What I want to know is how can I install the file to my repo after the MyBat.bat was executed?

I first wanted to use an mvn command from the bat file to upload it but this job gets executed from a Jenkins server and it has its own maven config. If I run mvn from the bat file it will refer to the maven on the local system.

Comment: Did i get it correctly you are calling Maven from the `scripts/MyBat.bat` file?

Comment: @khmarbaise 

The other way around... I have a maven project that calls a bat file. The bat file creates a external non jar library and after the bat file is executed I would like to be able to upload the external non jar library that was created

Comment: Ah Ok now i got it. Added appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to add the supplemental artifact to your build and afterwards it will be deployed in one go with the rest which can be done like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>some file</file>
                  <type>extension of your file </type>
                  <classifier>optional</classifier>
                </artifact>
                ...
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

May be you should bind the exec-maven-plugin to an earlier phase or the build-helper-maven-plugin to a later phase. I would suggest to use `prepare-package` for the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). Furthermore i would suggest to use uptodate versions of the plugins.

Comment: This is what I wanted and the prepare-package for the exec-maven-plug works very well. Thanks